# Editing Magento custom theme template files vs layout

Tags: magento

I’m fairly new to Magento themes and have been looking around for best practices for building them.  I have an understanding of creating a skeleton structure for my theme and copying template files from the base theme.  What I’m not sure of is, if for example I wanted to customise the product view, is it best practice to remove blocks from the view.phtml file or should I remove them in the layout file?  I want a fairly simple product page with wishlist, compare, tags etc removed.

Many thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: I would remove them in the layout rather than just in the template because it’s more clear and consistent that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove from both from xml you will find handle catalog_product_view you need to remove code as well as you need to remove from view.phtml file in folder of your new theme. At the end your code will be cleared and will take less time to execute.